# How to prevent Wordpress TinyMCE from stripping url having no link text

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm using a custom button on the TinyMCE editor on my wordpress site to insert a list of urls without having to type the markup. The problem is that TinyMCE automatically removes the urls that do not have a link text. For example, if the custom button is programmed to insert

```
<a href="http://example.com"></a>
```

well, nothing is inserted.

But if I make the button insert

```
<a href="http://example.com">Example.com</a>
```

it works.
I do not want a link text as I need an image link by using background image sprite instead of by using html img tag.

Is there any way I could prevent tinymce stripping links that have no link text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myformatTinyMCE($in) {
    $in['verify_html']=false;
    return $in;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'myformatTinyMCE' );
```

This option enables or disables the element cleanup functionality. If you set this option to false, all element cleanup will be skipped but other cleanup functionality such as URL conversion will still be executed.

Comment: Could you tell me where I should put that code? And can I use "tiny_mce_before_init" filter with $in['verify_html']=false;  ?

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks a lot. I will be updating your answer with the exact wordpress codes.