# How to prevent Wordpress 3.9 / TinyMCE 4 from stripping <style> tags?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce-4

Up until WP 3.9 I could specify inline Stylesheets using `<style>` tags in WP's "Text" tab, which would survive switching to WYSIWYG.

From WP 3.9, TinyMCE will strip `<style>` tags upon switching to WYSIWYG.

I've tried the following as MU plugin, but it doesn't help:

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'vsl2014_filter_tiny_mce_before_init');
function vsl2014_filter_tiny_mce_before_init( $options ) {

    if ( ! isset( $options['extended_valid_elements'] ) )
        $options['extended_valid_elements'] = '';

    $options['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',style';
    return $options;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try specifying [`valid_children`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration%3avalid_children) and [`custom_elements`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acustom_elements):

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'vsl2014_filter_tiny_mce_before_init');
function vsl2014_filter_tiny_mce_before_init( $options ) {

    if ( ! isset( $options['extended_valid_elements'] ) ) {
        $options['extended_valid_elements'] = 'style';
    } else {
        $options['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',style';
    }

    if ( ! isset( $options['valid_children'] ) ) {
        $options['valid_children'] = '+body[style]';
    } else {
        $options['valid_children'] .= ',+body[style]';
    }

    if ( ! isset( $options['custom_elements'] ) ) {
        $options['custom_elements'] = 'style';
    } else {
        $options['custom_elements'] .= ',style';
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: You just need to add `style` to the `$options['extended_valid_elements']` string, so the first `if` in the above will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a custom template to achieve your goals? When used in combination with Advanced Custom Fields this would allow you to control the markup, which you could then style using your stylesheet in style.css, taking it out of the hands of the client completely.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: I'm my own client. I have various small stylesheets applying only to a single page, and I want them editable inline, not hardcoded.

Comment: You could go into Appearance > Editor (/wp-admin/theme-editor.php) to edit the styles in style.css from the Wordpress back-end.

Comment: I'm only interested in fixing the described regression, not circumventing it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18313848. Works for me.

```
function myformatTinyMCE($in) {
$in['verify_html']=false;
    return $in;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'myformatTinyMCE' );
```

Comment: It says "all element cleanup will be skipped". I'm only interested in allowing style tags, not skipping cleanup altogether.